# Scroll to top after route has changed (nested divs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autoscroll, ngroute, ng-view

I'm using angularJS with ngRoute. When the user scrolls down and then changes the route the new page is scrolled down as well. I have read about using `autoscroll="true"` with `ngView` attribute. But my problem is that because of my HTML structure the scrolling container is **NOT** my `ngView`. In my case it looks kind of this:

```
<body>
    <!-- main container allows overflow scrolling and should be scrolled to top -->
    <main>
        <!-- this container has no scrolling -->
        <div ngView><!-- content comes here --></div>
    </main>
</body>
```

So that's why an `autoscroll="true"` on my `ngView` does nothing as there is nothing to scroll. What should be scrolled is the container above my `ngView` (`main` in this case).

**How could I do this? I'd prefer as less/easy JS as possible. A HTML solution like the autoscroll property would be nice ofcourse.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do this. I've created a directive that will scroll to the top of my container every time the route has been changed. I can listen to this via the `$routeChangeSuccess` event in `$rootScope`. The `scrollTop()` function is part of jQuery which I'm using anyway.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- scrollable content container -->
<main id="pageWrap" scroll-top-on-route-change>
    <!-- non-scrollable page content, templates inserted by ngView -->
    <div id="pageContent" ng-view></div>
</main>
```

**JS:**

```
app.directive("scrollTopOnRouteChange", [
    "$rootScope",
    function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link : function ($scope, $element) {
                $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {
                    $element.scrollTop(0);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```